# C# error XmlElement' is not valid on this declaration type.

Tags: c#, xml

after following tutorial on youtube, still having thie error:

> XmlElement' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on
>   'property, indexer, field, param, return' declarations

sample of the code :

```
[XmlRoot("cmdCommunicate")]
public class CMDCommunicate
{
    [XmlElement("login")]
    public Login loginData { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("injectionType")]
    public InjectionType injectionType { get; set; }
}
```

here where i am getting the error

```
[XmlElement("login")]
public class Login
{
    [XmlElement("server")]
    public string Server{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can't have an `XmlElement` attribute on a class, remove it.

Comment: The error is very obvious and is telling you in plain English what the problem is: You cannot have an `XmlElementAttribute` annotated to a class declaration. Now how to "fix" that? I don't know. What do you *want* to do?

Comment: I want to have this type of XML<br> <cmd..> <br> <login> <br> <server /> </login> </cmd... <

Comment: @godvshell Without an [mcve] it's hard to tell what you need to change.

Comment: found the problem, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it worked by changing the 
`[XmlElement("login")]` 
to:c 
 `[XmlRoot("login")]`

Comment: This is not a solution, because if you completely remove [XmlElement] from a class result will still be the same, because of  [XmlElement("login")] on the property in CMDCommunicate class